# How to uninstall Visual Studio 2012 so I can install a pre-keyed version ? Registry keys??

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation, key

I installed VS2012 from the web then joined a company that has a copy of VS2012 with the keys built in.. So I uninstalled the version from the web and installed the company version but I still get the "3 days left...."

So is there more uninstallation I must do somehow   ?  Perhaps some registry keys??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6fadba03-5b07-47b1-9f5e-ed207462d411/how-to-completely-uninstall-vs-2012-rc?forum=vssetup

> If your OS is Win 7:
>
> - Clear your **%temp%** folder, they are all temp files. Ignore those files you cannot delete.
> - We may need to reset templates. Open Windows Explorer, and navigate to  \Common7\IDE (by default      x86
>     OS C:\Program Files \Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE
>     x64 OS C:\Program Files(x86) \Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE
>     );
> - Delete the **ItemTemplatesCache, ProjectTemplatesCache** folder;
> - Open Visual Studio Command Prompt (2012) under Start menu -> All Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 -> Visual Studio Tools (run
>     it with Administrator privilege: right-click the program -> Run as
>     administrator);
> - Run the **devenv /InstallVSTemplates** switch
> - Run the **devenv /Setup** switch
>
> If reset templates did no help, try reset Visual Studio
>
> - Open Visual Studio Command Prompt (2012) under Start menu -> All Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2012  -> Visual Studio Tools (run
>     it with Administrator privilege: right-click the program -> Run as
>     administrator);
> - Try some devenv switches in command prompt:
>
>   1. Run **devenv /Resetsettings** to eliminate the cause of corrupted settings.
>   2. Run **devenv /ResetSkipPkgs** in Command Prompt.
>   3. Run **devenv /Safemode** to see if you can apply it correctly. This can eliminate the possibility that third party Add-ins or
>        packages are causing problems.
> - Switch and try a new user account. This can rule out the possibility of corrupted user profile.
>
> If you OS is Win 8, try to use All APPs page and open the prompt.
>
> Also, you can try to run setup to repair Visual Studio.

If that doesn't work I would suggest uninstalling and reinstalling.